# XNA Game failing to deploy to WP7 Emulator

Tags: xna, windows-phone-7

This use to work, I can't tell what I broke... but I suspect it is something to do with the WMAAppManifest / Guid...

When I attempt to Deply/Debug to the WP7 Emulator from VS I get the following popup message: "The application could not be launched for debugging. Verify that the application is installed on the target device."

What I actually want to do is deploy to the emulator in code using the Microsoft.Smartdevice.Connectivity assembly. The error message I am getting there is perhaps more informative.

```
        app = WP7Device.InstallApplication(
            ApplicationGuid,
            ApplicationGuid,
            "NormalApp",
            outputPathAbsolute + "GameThumbnail.png",
            outputPathAbsolute + xapFilename                
            );
```

...Generates the following exception, "Installation of the application failed. XAP package signature is not valid or the WP manifest file is invalid. Re-sign with valid signature and fix the manifest file."

I have verified that the path to the XAP is correct, and the value of the ApplicationGuid parameter matches this value in my WMAppManifest.xml "ProductID="{4b8343da-c890-423b-9b76-2754015174cf}".

So... "Re-sign with a valid signature and fix the manifest file." If that is really the problem, how?

Edit:

So I opened the XAP with IZarc and behold, the WMAppManifest inside it is NOT the one in my project, and has a different Guid. How is this possible?

Comment: Is your problem deploying from VS2010 or using `InstallApplication`? It's not clear which you're asking help for. Ask one questions at a time. Include details of what you've tried and what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also found this problem during deploymet of my Application. The solution is simple - you must replace 1st argument of InstallApplication method with Product GUID (which is different from Application GUID). You can find Product GUID in **Properties\WMAppManifest.xml** file, inside  tag.
2nd argument must be guid from **AssemblyInfo.cs**.

Comment: I am no longer working on this issue, but, if someone else can confirm this works, I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the solution and select properties. After selecting the properties go to configuration properties and check the build and deploy option.